# Increased intracranial space

Tags: creature-design, xenobiology, species

The brain is 1 major developmental difference between us and these humanoids.

These humanoids start off with larger brains to begin with and so brain development in the womb happens at about the same pace as ours, just with more cells.

This larger brain means that babies soon go from not being able to move at all to being able to climb. Climbing is their first physical milestone because the species has an underground civilization.

As early as 3 months they can say single words like "Hungry" and can stand with support.

At 6 months they can walk with support and say phrases and short sentences like "Head hurts" and "I love you".

At 9 months they can walk without support and ask questions like "Why does my tummy hurt?".

At 1 year old they can run and jump and from 2-5 years old they start to understand why they are hurt and learn how to prevent themselves from getting hurt.

This is all during the gender neutral phase where there are no external genitalia but there are internal genitalia and gender has already been genetically determined.

Now I made these humanoids have increased intracranial space because of a viral infection called Viral TB which can infect every organ but unlike regular TB is not a lifelong infection when it isn't treated.

When Viral TB infects the brain it swells up. The increased intracranial space allows for more fluid balance and oxygen transport during any kind of brain infection.

But is the increased intracranial space beneficial for anything other than more fluid balance and oxygen transport when the brain swells up?

Comment: You're saying this species lives in symbiosis with a virus?  If they don't contract this virus in-utero, how would they progress?  Also, worth noting is that the real reason why we can't stand or walk at young age is because H. sapiens sacrifices *dearly* to get that big brain through the birth canal.  I assume your species has solved this?  If so, they'd likely develop the larger brain spaces without any viral help.

Comment: No they aren't in symbiosis with the virus. Rather they evolved the increased intracranial space because of the virus.

Comment: Not sure how a larger brain is meant to accelerate development.  If anything I'd have thought it would make it slower.  If the constraints that cause humans to be born helpless have been overcome, I'd expect the babies to be born more capable rather than to develop more quickly.

Comment: The short version: Childbirth is going to have a higher fatality rate (mothers and babies), birthrates will drop.

Comment: Ah but these humanoids have a very elastic birth canal(much more elastic than ours) so that would increase the birth rate in any pregnancy, even dodecuplets which are very rare to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into density and gray matter as well. Brain size isn't the only qualifier for greater cognitive function.

**[io9: 4 Biggest Myths About the Human Brain](http://io9.gizmodo.com/5890414/the-4-biggest-myths-about-the-human-brain)**

**[Smithsonian Magazine: Why Brain Size Doesn't Correlate With Intelligence](http://www.smithsonianmag.com/science-nature/why-brain-size-doesnt-correlate-with-intelligence-180947627/?no-ist)**

**[The Journal of Neuroscience, November 15, 2001, 21(22):8819–8829: Mapping Continued Brain Growth and Gray Matter Density
Reduction in Dorsal Frontal Cortex: Inverse Relationships during
Postadolescent Brain Maturation](http://www.jneurosci.org/content/21/22/8819.full.pdf)**

**[Live Science: Specific Genes Linked to Big Brains and Intelligence](http://www.livescience.com/19692-genes-brain-size-intelligence.html)**

I can't give an answer as to what specific effects a larger intracranial cavity would have. I did however find some interesting tidbits that could be of use to you, regarding this 'virus' and Crouzon syndrome. Hopefully these will be of use, or give you some new ideas.

**[Journal of Neurosurgery, 2005 Sep;103(3 Suppl):238-46.: Intracranial space, brain, and cerebrospinal fluid volume measurements obtained with the aid of three-dimensional computerized tomography in patients with and without Crouzon syndrome.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16238077)**

**[IHS Classification ICHD-II: Headache attributed to space-occupying intracranial infectious lesion or infestation|A9.1.6|](http://ihs-classification.org/en/02_klassifikation/05_anhang/09.01.06_anhang.html)**